# How to search a directory and display search results in a table in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, search, spotlight

I want to create an iTunes style search function where a searchfield will look through the contents of a directory and display the results in an `NSTableView`.
This would be specifically for music so the searchfield should match either song name, artist name or song name.

Is there a way to do this in Objective-C without having the contents of the directory added into the `NSTableView` first?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use **Spotlight** for searching meta-data like artists and other song information:

- [Introduction to Spotlight](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/MetadataIntro/MetadataIntro.html)
- [Spotlight query sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SpotlightFortunes/Introduction/Intro.html)

SearchKit focus OTOH is on content search.

Answer (score 0):

where is the "directory" located? are you talking about an actual directory on your local filesystem?
I suggesting populating an array with the contents of a directory listing and then using on of the many howto's to get a search to populate a tableView.

http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSTableViewTutorial lesson 6

Answer (score 0):

This is generally what [SearchKit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SearchKitConcepts/searchKit_intro/searchKit_intro.html) is for. It gives you access to the spotlight metadata, so that you can search for information like this very quickly.

Comment: SearchKit is for content. From Apple Docs: *"If your application focuses on metadata rather than document content, you may want to consider using Spotlight instead."*